# Unir varios diccionarios a un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios, pycharm

Tengo este código que viene de un archivo CSV en donde lo llama y luego lo ordena:

```
def ordenar(lista0,lista1,lista2):
    global dic
    for i in range(1,len(lista0)):
        h=i
        while h > 0 and lista2[h] < lista2[h - 1]:
            cambio0 = lista0[h]
            lista0[h] = lista0[h - 1]
            lista0[h - 1] = cambio0
            cambio1 = lista1[h]
            lista1[h] = lista1[h - 1]
            lista1[h - 1] = cambio1
            cambio2 = lista2[h]
            lista2[h] = lista2[h - 1]
            lista2[h - 1] = cambio2
            h=h-1
        dic = {'Departamento': lista0, 'Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana': lista1, 'No tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana': lista2}
    return dic
import csv
dic = {}
lista0 = []
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
i = 0
with open("servicio_agua.csv") as archivo_csv:
    archivo = csv.reader(archivo_csv, delimiter=",")
    contador_linea = 0
    for fila in archivo:
        if contador_linea > 0:
            numero1 = int(fila[1][3:])
            numero2 = int(fila[2][3:])

            porcentajesi = round((numero1/(numero2+numero1))*100,2)
            porcentajeno = round((numero2/(numero1+numero2))*100,2)

            lista0.append(fila[0][1:])
            lista1.append(porcentajeno)
            lista2.append(porcentajesi)

        contador_linea +=1
ordenar(lista0,lista1,lista2)
print(dic['No tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana'])
print(dic['Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana'])
print(dic['Departamento'])
```

Que me imprime estos porcentajes:

```
[6.2, 61.36, 66.93, 68.12, 68.95, 76.14, 80.42, 84.1, 84.19, 84.31, 85.14, 85.82, 86.59, 86.62, 86.92, 87.11, 87.16, 88.12, 88.65, 89.64, 90.5, 91.38, 91.62, 91.97, 93.63]
[93.8, 38.64, 33.07, 31.88, 31.05, 23.86, 19.58, 15.9, 15.81, 15.69, 14.86, 14.18, 13.41, 13.38, 13.08, 12.89, 12.84, 11.88, 11.35, 10.36, 9.5, 8.62, 8.38, 8.03, 6.37]
['Lima', 'Tumbes', 'Pasco', 'Ica', 'Piura', 'Amazonas', 'La Libertad', 'Cajamarca', 'Loreto', 'Huánuco', 'Puno', 'Junín', 'Ayacucho', 'San Martín', 'Huancavelica', 'Cusco', 'Arequipa', 'Apurímac', 'Áncash', 'Moquegua', 'Madre de Dios', 'Ucayali', 'Lambayeque', 'Tacna', 'Provincia Constitucional del Callao']
```

Pero intento que me imprima: [ ['Lima':[6.2][93.8] ] , algo así. Les agradecería mucho que me ayuden con mi problema, si tiene alguna consejo para poder mejorar mi código estaría muy agradecida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura que buscas es un diccionario, en el que las claves serían las ciudades como `"Lima"`, y los valores serían una lista, como `[6.2, 93.8]`. El problema de los diccionarios es que, a menos que uses una versión de Python 3.7 o superior, no mantienen el orden de inserción. Es decir, que pueden salirte las ciudades en cualquier orden (aunque eso sí, asociadas a su lista de valores correctamente).

Otra solución quizás pueda ser que imprimas los valores como "trios", en los que el primer elemento sería el nombre de la ciudad y los dos siguientes serían los números en cuestión. Es decir, algo como `("Lima", 6.2, 93.8)`. Esta estructura de datos se llama Tupla.

O quizás quieres imprimir algo más descriptivo como:

```
Lima:    sin_agua=6.2    con_agua=93.8
etc.
```

En cualquiera de los tres casos el problema se reduce al mismo: juntar información que tienes dispersa en tres listas, pero recorriendo las tres listas "a la vez" para obtener los elementos que ocupan la misma posición en cada una de ellas.

Para resolver este problema se usa `zip()` que es una función que recibe una serie de iterables y te va devolviendo tuplas, cada una de ellas compuesta por un valor sacado de cada uno de los iterables. `zip()` es a su vez iterable, y en cada iteración te devuelve una de esas tuplas. Por ejemplo en la primera devolvería `("Lima", 6.2, 93.8)`, en la segunda `("Tumbes", 61.36, 38.64)`, etc.

Usando `zip()` veamos cómo implementar entonces cada una de las ideas anteriores.

#### Mostrar tríos

Directamente son los valores devueltos por `zip()`, así que sería tan simple como:

```
for trio in zip(lista0, lista1, lista2):
   print(trio)
```

#### Crear un diccionario

Los valores que devuelve `zip()`, ya que son trios, se pueden desempaquetar en tres variables, y usar éstas para el diccionario:

```
diccionario = {}
for depto, sin_agua, con_agua in zip(lista0, lista1, lista2):
  diccionario[depto] = [sin_agua, con_agua]
print(diccionario)
```

Esto mismo puede escribirse en una sola línea haciendo uso de una *comprensión de diccionarios*:

```
diccionario = { depto: [sin_agua, con_agua] for depto, sin_agua, con_agua in zip(lista0, lista1, lista2) }
```

(Gracias a @ChemaCortes por recordarme que incluyera esta forma)

#### Información formateada

Usando la misma idea anterior y una cadena de formato adecuada:

```
for depto, sin_agua, con_agua in zip(lista0, lista1, lista2):
    print("{:20s} sin_agua={:6s} con_agua={:6s}".format(depto, sin_agua, con_agua))
```

Las opciones `:20s` (`:6s`, etc.) son para que imprima ese campo como cadena ocupando 20 caracteres (respectivamente 6), y de este modo quede todo mejor alineado como en una tabla.

Comment: Hay una forma más compacta de crear el diccionario usando _compresiones_; `diccionario = { depto: [sin_agua, con_agua] for (depto, sin_agua, con_agua) in zip(lista0, lista1, lista2) }`

Comment: @ChemaCortes No tenía otra idea que poner también esto en la misma sección que el diccionario, y al final se me olvidó hacerlo. Gracias por recordármelo!

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es crear una clase iterable que contenga la información. Las clases iterables pueden ser ordenadas usando `sorted()`.

Para que una clase sea iterable, tiene que tener implementando el metodo `__iter(self)__`. La llamada a este método debe retornar un *iterable* o un *generador*.

En este caso usare un *generador* (son mucho más fáciles). Un generador es una función que puede retornar valores sin dejar de ejecutar. Los valores se retornan usando `yield` en vez de `return`.

En este caso, el generador va recorriendo las tres listas en paralelo (usando `zip`) y retornando cada trío de valores.

Agrego esta declaración al comienzo de tu programa:

```
class ListaOrdenada(object):
    def __init__(self, lista1, lista2, lista3):
        self.zip = zip(lista1, lista2, lista3)

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.zip:
            yield item
```

Es una simple clase que recibe las tres listas.

Puedes eliminar la función `ordenar`. Ya no es necesaria.

Después de completar las tres listas, para ordenar e imprimir simplemente ocupas:

```
for ciudad in sorted(ListaOrdenada(lista1, lista2, lista3)):
    print(ciudad)
```

La variable `ciudad` es una lista de tres elementos, los cuales puedes formatear a tu gusto y necesidad:

- `ciudad[0]` contiene el nombre de la ciudad.
- `ciudad[1]` son los deptos con agua.
- `ciudad[2]` son los deptos sin agua.

Nota: esto reemplaza las cuatro últimas líneas de tu programa.

**Comprobación**

El programa de prueba

```
class ListaOrdenada(object):
    def __init__(self, lista1, lista2, lista3):
        self.zip = zip(lista1, lista2, lista3)

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.zip:
            yield item

sin_agua = [6.2, 61.36, 66.93, 68.12, 68.95, 76.14, 80.42, 84.1, 84.19, 84.31, 85.14, 85.82, 86.59, 86.62, 86.92, 87.11, 87.16, 88.12, 88.65, 89.64, 90.5, 91.38, 91.62, 91.97, 93.63]
con_agua = [93.8, 38.64, 33.07, 31.88, 31.05, 23.86, 19.58, 15.9, 15.81, 15.69, 14.86, 14.18, 13.41, 13.38, 13.08, 12.89, 12.84, 11.88, 11.35, 10.36, 9.5, 8.62, 8.38, 8.03, 6.37]
ciudades = ['Lima', 'Tumbes', 'Pasco', 'Ica', 'Piura', 'Amazonas', 'La Libertad', 'Cajamarca', 'Loreto', 'Huánuco', 'Puno', 'Junín', 'Ayacucho', 'San Martín', 'Huancavelica', 'Cusco', 'Arequipa', 'Apurímac', 'Áncash', 'Moquegua', 'Madre de Dios', 'Ucayali', 'Lambayeque', 'Tacna', 'Provincia Constitucional del Callao']

for ciudad in sorted(ListaOrdenada(ciudades, con_agua, sin_agua)):
    print(ciudad)
```

produce:

```
('Amazonas', 23.86, 76.14)
('Apurímac', 11.88, 88.12)
('Arequipa', 12.84, 87.16)
('Ayacucho', 13.41, 86.59)
('Cajamarca', 15.9, 84.1)
... etc ...
('San Martín', 13.38, 86.62)
('Tacna', 8.03, 91.97)
('Tumbes', 38.64, 61.36)
('Ucayali', 8.62, 91.38)
('Áncash', 11.35, 88.65)
```

Comment: Crear un objeto implica que los diccionarios o tuplas pierdan sus métodos nativos, esto dificulta el manejo de datos en un futuro.

Comment: @gcoronel99 Las listas originales no sea han perdido y tiene un método adaptable a generar cualquier otra estructura que el negocio necesite. Puedo ampliar la respuesta para explicar como adaptarla a algún tipo de datos que propongas.